# How can I use "for i in" with two variables?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, binary

I am currently adding finishing touches to a binary tool. I would like to check user input to make sure that there are only zeroes and ones in their input. I can get the check to work for one variable, but not two at the same time. I have done this so far:

```
for i in (firstvalue) & (secondvalue):
    if not (i in "01"):
        print("Please enter only zeroes and ones.")
        break
```

I also used to have the issue of the message printing for each individual character that was not a zero or one - however I resolved this issue with the `break` statement.

I have also tried `|` operator but returned with same error of unsupported operand type. Both `firstvalue` and `secondvalue` are currently strings but I can't really change them to `int` as this would mean losing any zeroes at the start of the inputted binary value.

Comment: Zip the two collections together, then unpack it as a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check both strings to contain only zeroes and ones, you may just concatenate them: `firstvalue + secondvalue`.

```
for i in firstvalue + secondvalue:
    if i not in "01":
        print("Please enter only zeroes and ones.")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice simple solution.